# drupal 7 parent menu item will not hide for authenticated user

Tags: routes, users

Could any one give me some ideas on what i need to check please?

I wish i could just show the site, but of course it' for my company, so I can't,  but I have a menu bar at top of my page home, contact, meet the authors, books;

Under "Meet the authors", i have several authors, I created an authors content type and have one for each author. When you hover over "Meet the Authors" you see the drop-down list/sub-menus of the authors - only five of them now.

so using panels and views, when you click of "meet the authors" you see a list of the authors on the page and can click in for more detail.

Using the access control module, I only want this link to appear for anonymous users, once logged-in, this link should disappear but the link will not hide itself after login, but here is what's really odd, the sub-links which are the authors, those links/sub-menu do/does hide when the user logs in and only displays for the anonymous user

so for example, this enable menu should appear for the **anonymous** user

Meet the authors
 - ----Kim Fields
 - ----Tony Bruewer
 - ----Harris Carlton
 - ----John Brown

and should be completely hidden for the authenticated user, but what is happening though, upon login, the user sees the parent menu:
Meet the authors

but the sub menus have hidden themselves as they should, i just can't get the parent menu to hide itself.

I have checked the access control to make sure I have selected things properly.  I even created test content type and menus to test and everything worked, so I assume there is something different, but I just can't see what and where.

Any ideas and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Notes: the parent menu about [Meet the authors] is pointing to a panel page that contains a view to display the list of authors.  I do not have access setting on the panel.

***More Information***:
So for my own sanity, I slowly created another content type, a view for that content type and a panel page.  Saved, cleared cache, ran cron.  Change settings in control access module.  Here is what I now see-- The sub-menus of the parent menu [Meet the authors]are following the authentication rule, the top menu just displays all the time.  I create this mention from the Structure->Menus navigation.  So the top menu item is pointing to the panel whereas the sub-menu items are actually the content types.

**Still more Info:**
Here is what I think the issue that I still have not found a way around.  I create the view, create the panel, place the view in the panel, give the panel page a normal menu entry.  So that is my menu item that appears.  If I click on that top parent link, it takes me to the panel with my view, but the menu item won't display/hide as needed.  So i realized that the menu I am creating in the panel has nothing to do with the content type and the content type is needed to manage the access control module.  So I go into my content type, change one of it's types and change the menu to point to the panel url I created.  Well when I do that, that url is assigned to that content type node, not panel, but the menu item does, now, display/hide based on the selection from the access control module.

Can anyone give me a way around this?  What i think I need is a way to point one of my node content types to the panel.  Does this make sense.  I love Drupal, but sometimes...

Comment: what happens if you click on the parent item? i.e. is the access control actually working to restrict access to the page.

Comment: Hi Geoff - see the "still more info" note i added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally resolved this issue, or figured out what is going on.  This is a very specific issue, so posting my solution here, should someone else run into this exact problem.

Ok, so I am using panels in my sites, inside the panels, i have views based on the content types.  My top level/parent menu item is pointing to the Panel that holds the View.

The menu item is **NOT** a menu created of/from the content type consequently, the "control access module" didn't do anything with the menu item, because it does not consider it a content type and that is actually correct.

So you know the saying "**there's a module for that**" -- there is a **menu_per_role** module that allowed me to update visibility based on **user role**, so I could hide that menu for the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with the least amount of programming would be do it with css:

```
body.logged-in .my-menu-name-or-css-class {
  display:none; 
}
```

The most standards compliant way would be to use hook_menu_alter and unset the menu if $user->uid returns true: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7

However, in this case you're probably looking at maybe saving 10kb of bandwidth by unsetting the menu vs. just using CSS to hide it.